# Results about conditional expectations

Tags: probability, random-variables, conditional-probability

$\theta$, $\phi$ are integrable random variables on a probability space $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},P)$ and $\mathcal{G}$ is $\sigma$-field on $\Omega$ contained in $\mathcal{F}$.
Now we want to prove $E(\theta\mid\mathcal{G})=E(\theta)$ if $\theta$ is independent of $\mathcal{G}$. The proof is, for any $B\in \mathcal{G}$, by independence, $\theta$ and $1_{B}$ are independent. And,$$\int_{B}E(\theta)dP=E(\theta)E(1_{B})=E(\theta 1_{B})=\int_{B}\theta dP,$$ and the conclusion follows. I'm really confused with the first equality $\int_{B}E(\theta)dP=E(\theta)E(1_{B})$. Can anyone explain this to me? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

For every real number $a$, one has: $\int\limits_Ba\mathrm dP=a\int\limits_B\mathrm dP=aP[B]$. Furthermore, $P[B]=E[I_B]$. Apply these to $a=E[\theta]$.

Answer (score 0):

$$\int_{B}E[\theta]dP=E[E[\theta]I_{B}]=E[I_{B}]E[\theta]$$,that's all.

Comment: The first step helps me out, but I guess the second step needs some more details. $E(\theta)$ cannot be treated as a constant, so we have to add some details about the conditioning set for the second step. Just some supplements. Thanks!!

Comment: $E（\theta）$ is a constant,which is independent of $\omega\in \Omega$